# Sencha Touch 2: input placeholder in not centered in Android 4

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch-2, alignment, text-alignment

I'm trying to center the placeholder text. It looks centered on IOS, but still left aligned on Android 4.

```
/*css code is below*/
    #myinput input{
        text-align:center!important;
     }
    #myinput input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        text-align:center!important;
     }


//the view (.js file) has
{
    xtype: 'emailfield',
    name: 'myinput',
    id: 'myinput',
    required: true,
    placeHolder: 'myinput (optional)',
    listeners: {
      //some listeners are here
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a bug here :(, centering just won't work. You can use this polyfill: https://github.com/diy/jquery-placeholder and it supports the "force" attribute. That attribute makes it run even on browser that "support" placeholder, like android.

```
$('#myInput').placeholder({force:true});
```

Then use regular CSS to style the placeholder class provided by the plugin

```
.placeholder{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to write this is as below:

```
#myinput::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        text-align:center!important;
}
```

No "input" after #myinput, try it!